# I need help for binary search algorithm in C programming

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

struct node * add(struct node * root,int newData){
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        struct node * root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        root->data=newData;
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
        return root;
    }
    
    struct node * tmp = root;
    if (tmp->data<newData)
        tmp->right = add(tmp->right,newData);
    if (tmp->data >newData)
        tmp->left = add(tmp->left,newData);
}



void pre_order_traversal(struct node* root) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return;
    if(root != NULL) {
      printf("%d ",root->data);
      pre_order_traversal(root->left);
      pre_order_traversal(root->right);
   }
}

void inorder_traversal(struct node* root) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return;
   if(root != NULL) {
      inorder_traversal(root->left);
      printf("%d ",root->data);          
      inorder_traversal(root->right);
   }
}

void post_order_traversal(struct node* root) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return;
   if(root != NULL) {
      post_order_traversal(root->left);
      post_order_traversal(root->right);
      printf("%d ", root->data);
   }
}

int main(){
    struct node * tree1 = NULL;
    tree1 = add(tree1,5);
    tree1 = add(tree1,17);
    tree1 = add(tree1,21);
    tree1 = add(tree1,19);
    

    pre_order_traversal(tree1);
}
```

When i run this code i get this error
Segmentation fault (core dump)

Comment: Don't post images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: If you get a core dump, then you should examine it.  It will provide a great deal of information about the seg fault.

Comment: The compiler warning is pretty explanatory: `warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `return root` or `return tmp` at the end of `add`.